# Is it possible to convert data types such as long to view?

Tags: android

I just want to get the ID of a certain file then convert it to view so that I can use drag and drop method.

Here is the code:

```
View x = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
```

and it state'st that "Type mismatch cannot convert long to view"...

So, Is there a way to get the Id of a file then bind it with view for me to implement the drag and drop ? .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of file is this?

Comment: File which are located in sdcards such as textfiles and pictures

Comment: getItemId returns an id, which is a long.

Comment: - a long is a primitive type that stores a long integer in 8 bytes.
- a view is a complex object with many methods and fields encapsulated within it
...Apples and Oranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A long is not a View. There is a large amount of data and logic that powers a View (such as the code to draw and measure the View) that simply isn't in a long. How would you like Android/Java to convert a simple number into a graphical object?

What you *can* do is use the data from a file to populate a View.
For example, to use a picture from the SD card to set the image of an ImageView:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() "Images/my-image.jpg";
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Similarly you could read data from a text file to populate a TextView.